# Use DLL with python and ctypes

Tags: python, dll, autoit

I would like to use a DLL (ImageSearch.dll) for my python project. It was initially developped for autoit.
Here is the au3 file:

```
Func _ImageSearchArea($findImage,$resultPosition,$x1,$y1,$right,$bottom,ByRef $x, ByRef $y, $tolerance)
    ;MsgBox(0,"asd","" & $x1 & " " & $y1 & " " & $right & " " & $bottom)
    if $tolerance>0 then $findImage = "*" & $tolerance & " " & $findImage
    $result = DllCall("ImageSearchDLL.dll","str","ImageSearch","int",$x1,"int",$y1,"int",$right,"int",$bottom,"str",$findImage)

    ; If error exit
    if $result[0]="0" then return 0

    ; Otherwise get the x,y location of the match and the size of the image to
    ; compute the centre of search
    $array = StringSplit($result[0],"|")

   $x=Int(Number($array[2]))
   $y=Int(Number($array[3]))
   if $resultPosition=1 then
      $x=$x + Int(Number($array[4])/2)
      $y=$y + Int(Number($array[5])/2)
   endif
   return 1
EndFunc
```

So I try to use ctypes but I have problems to get the variable "result". Indeed, in the following script, the value of searchReturn is c_char_p(b'0') whereas with the autoit script, I have a string with '|' inside it.

```
from ctypes import *

ImageSearchDLL = windll.LoadLibrary("ImageSearchDLL")
ImageSearch = ImageSearchDLL.ImageSearch
searchReturn = c_char_p(ImageSearch(0,0,1919,1079,'myPic.bmp'))

print(searchReturn)
```

I also try to pass arguments with c_int, etc. and it leads to the same problem. If I don't use the c_char_p(), I have an int. I don't understand why I got an int, the header shows that it should return a str.

Comment: "I have problems" and "it doesn't work" are not helpful.  Please describe the problems and what happens when it doesn't work.

Comment: I put more details, sorry.

Comment: Is the DLL written in C/C++, or something like C#?  One of the issues is the calling convention.  `windll` uses the `stdcall` calling convention, `cdll` uses `cdecl`, the C and C++ calling convention.  The calling convention is concerned with argument order and stack clearance.  What complicates is that C and C++ can use either calling convention on Windows, you have to know which to use it.  You really need the C equivalents of the types.

Comment: Ok I keep searching and I think I found some interessant things. All paramaters are int except one which is a char*. The return type is a char*. I know that the dll is written in c or c++. I got a new error : "ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (20 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention".

Comment: What did you change to get the ValueError?   You say that all parameters are `int`, but one you show as `myPic.bmp`.  I suggest this should be a bytes object, since you appear to be using Python 3: `b'myPic.bmp'`

Answer (score 1):

Ok I thought I should use cdll but after many attempts and defining arguments with the good way, I solve my problem. Thank you cdarke for your help :)

Here is the final script :

```
import ctypes

dllFunc = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('ImageSearchDLL.dll')
dllFunc.ImageSearch.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_char_p,)
dllFunc.ImageSearch.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

_result = dllFunc.ImageSearch(0, 0, 1920, 1080, b"myPic.bmp")
print(_result.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Good!  I wrote my comment before I saw this.